# How do I drag and drop elements using React dnd?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I need to load a part of the map and be able to drag some icons onto that map. The icons are arranged side by side in a column and must transfer their copy to the board. And then the icons can be moved around the map. At the moment it works for me, but the icons on the board move when copying.

I don't understand how to move around the board?

```
function DrugDrop() {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState({
    a: { id: 1, top: 20, left: 20, el: <AddLocation /> },
    b: { id: 2, top: 60, left: 20, el: <Comment /> },
    c: { id: 3, top: 100, left: 20, el: <Abc /> },
    d: { id: 4, top: 140, left: 20, el: <AssistWalker /> },
    e: { id: 5, top: 180, left: 20, el: <AttachFile /> },
    f: { id: 6, top: 220, left: 20, el: <PrintOut /> },
    g: { id: 7, top: 260, left: 20, el: <QrCodeScanner /> },
    h: { id: 8, top: 300, left: 20, el: <AppsStore /> },
    r: { id: 9, top: 340, left: 20, el: <NearMe /> },
  });

  console.log(board, "77-2465-2356-535-12");

  function generateUniqueKey() {
    const uniKey = new Date();
    return uniKey;
  }



  const moveBox = useCallback(
    (id, left, top, isCopy) => {
      if (left >= 20 && left <= 590 && top >= 20 && top <= 500) {
        setBoard((prevBoard) => ({
          ...prevBoard,
          [id]: {
            ...prevBoard[id],
            top,
            left,
            id,
          },
        }));
      }
      if (!isCopy) {
        const newId = generateUniqueKey();
        const updatedBoard = (prevBoard) => ({
          ...board,
          [newId]: {
            top,
            left,
            el: prevBoard[id].el,
          },
        });
        setBoard(updatedBoard);
      }
    },
    [board]
  );

  const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop(
    () => ({
      accept: ItemTypes.ICON,
      drop(item, monitor) {
        const delta = monitor.getDifferenceFromInitialOffset();
        const left = Math.round(item.left + delta.x);
        const top = Math.round(item.top + delta.y);
        moveBox(item.id, left, top);
        return undefined;
      },
      collect: (monitor) => ({
        isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
      }),
    }),
    [moveBox]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <div className="head">
        <Form />
      </div>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="board" ref={drop} style={styles}></div>
        <div className="icons" style={{ opacity: isOver ? 0.5 : 3 }}>
          {Object.keys(board).map((key) => {
            const { left, top, el } = board[key];
            return (
              <Icon key={key} id={key} left={left} top={top} el={el}>
                {el}
              </Icon>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default DrugDrop;


function Icon({ id, left, top, el }) {
  const [isDragging, drag] = useDrag(
    () => ({
      type: ItemTypes.ICON,
      item: {
        id,
        left,
        top,
      },
      collect: (monitor) => ({
        isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
      }),
    }),
    [id, left, top]
  );

  return (
    <div className="icon" ref={drag} style={{ ...style, left, top }}>
      {el}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Icon;
```